# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Wordpress/WPML/WP Google Maps

Tags: xml, wordpress, apache, cors

I'm getting the following errors on the console, when I switch between domains.

I understand the logic of why this is happening, but after reading around, I have zero idea how to fix this for XML files! Some assistance would be fantastic and greatly received!

```
GET http://en.example.com/wp-content/uploads/wp-google-maps/1markers.xml?u=1919 
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://en.example.com/wp-content/uploads/wp-google-maps/1markers.xml?u=1919. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://de.example.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Comment: I assume you have the wrong url address if you switched domains, but you have provided zero code to help someone understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a resource on the en.example.com domain **from** the de.example.com domain, which is not allowed.

As it looks like you're using WPML with the subdomain setup, you should be able to simply change `http://en.example.com/wp-content/uploads/wp-google-maps/1markers.xml?u=1919` to `http://de.example.com/wp-content/uploads/wp-google-maps/1markers.xml?u=1919` (changing en to de). This should ultimately point to the same content if your subdomain setup is correct.

For a more general solution that will work on more than simply a case by case basis, I would recommend generating your links dynamically in PHP based on the current language, like this:

```
global $sitepress;
$lang = $sitepress->get_current_language(); // Get the current language from WPML
$link = "http://".$lang.".example.com/wp-content/uploads/wp-google-maps/1markers.xml?u=1919";
```

This will ensure that you're always accessing your resources on the appropriate subdomain and don't run into cross-site scripting issues.